# TKinter Canvas 'dash' option is not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
canvas.create_line(50, 500, 950, 500, dash=(5, 1), tags="splitDistance")
```

This will create a line which looks like this:

```
XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX
```

5 dashes, 1 space and then repeat, as told by [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/dash-patterns.html) documentation

But when changing the 1 to any value, it will **not** change the gap size.

`dash=(5, 100)`:

```
XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX
```

---

Another weird behavior is that the first parameter only changes the outcome when it is dividable by 5 for example: (5, 10, 15, 20...)

`dash=(1, 1)`:

```
X X X X X X X X X X X X
```

`dash=(4, 1)`:

```
X X X X X X X X X X X X
```

`dash=(5, 1)`:

```
XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX
```

Here is a image from the program and result:

[image: image from the program and result]

Comment: `dash` works for me on Linux Mint. Maybe it depends on system. Or add in question minimal, working example with your problem - so we could run it and compare result.

Comment: Ok I added a picture. Im using Windows 10.

Comment: Just found a similar question which is 7 years old and has no answer.

http://smtp.grokbase.com/t/python/tkinter-discuss/099vgnqzr0/python-3-1-canvas-rectangle-dash-dashoffset

Comment: on Linux it looks like this: [canvas dash](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/canvas-dash). Seems problem is only on Windows - I can't help you.

Comment: From [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-October/070905.html) it sounds like it's system dependent thing. I get the same results as you one Windows 7 in both Python 2 & 3. Regardless, in the future please include the code in your question _as text_, not an image.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different platforms support different dash patterns. What you are seeing is the fact that Windows doesn't support the same dash patterns as X-based systems.

From the [canonical tcl/tk documentation on the `dash` attribute](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M18) comes these example (in tcl syntax, but the translation to tkinter is trivial):

```
-dash .     → -dash {2 4}
-dash -     → -dash {6 4}
-dash -.    → -dash {6 4 2 4}
-dash -..   → -dash {6 4 2 4 2 4}
-dash {. }  → -dash {2 8}
-dash ,     → -dash {4 4}
```

The documentation goes on to say this:

> On systems which support only a limited set of dash patterns, the dash pattern will be displayed as the closest dash pattern that is available. For example, on Windows only the first 4 of the above examples are available. The last 2 examples will be displayed identically to the first one.

Comment: Is there a way, to add dash patterns to Windows?

Comment: @user5508373: The only fix is to make sure you use a dash pattern supported by the platform you're running on.

Comment: Is it also system dependent whether or not the second parameter for the gap works? In my example it wont change the gap no matter which pattern I use.

Comment: @user5508373: yes. Different platforms support different dash patterns, and the second parameter is part of the definition of a dash pattern.